# Animations - from designer to developer

Tags: ios, animation

I want to implement some animations created by a designer for my iOS app. 
Those animation aren't complex, but they're involving UI, buttons and other  objects.

I know how to implement the animations with code, but it won't be 100% identical to the animations I got from the designer.

I want to know if there's a way to transfer the animation the designer created to my project exactly as they are, while those animation should work on existing objects at my app (so the animation won't create the objects, but animate an existing objects).

I've heard about Lottie (Haikue), and createwithflow, but AFAIK I can't use them for existing object, only for objects created by those frameworks.

Comment: Create extensions for UIComponents and add CABasicAnimation, CATransaction or other Core graphics animations to achieve your animation for UIComponents. That way you add funky animations to existing components and wont end up creating a new one :)

Comment: For UI elements, the only sensible options are using UIKit Animations (e.g. UIPropertyAnimator) and Core Animation. For any other kind of animation, those purely for decoration, you could export your animations from After Effects as JSON files and use them with Lottie.